# Overwrite/Merge two objects in JavaScript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want my user input to overwrite the defaults, but have the defaults fill in the blank if the data is not there. Like so:

```
var userInput={
    name:"Pat",
    color: "green"
}
var defaults={
    name:"Trevor",
    color: "blue",
    state: "washington"
}
var finalObject=mergeObjects(userInput,defaults);
//Should produce:
{
    name:"Pat",
    color: "green",
    state: "washington"
}
```

Is this kind of merging/overwriting possible with jQuery? I did see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1584370/how-to-merge-two-arrays-in-javascript) but it works with **arrays** and does **not** overwrite like I need it to.

Any ideas?

Comment: Learn about the tools you use: http://api.jquery.com/category/utilities/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

jQuery's [`$.extend()` method](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/) will do the trick:

```
var finalObject = $.extend({}, defaults, userInput);
```

Note that `$.extend()` modifies the object passed as the first argument (and returns it), so you probably want to pass an empty object so that your `defaults` and `userInput` don't get changed. You can pass as many objects as you like and they'll all get merged into the first one in the order supplied (so `defaults` comes before `userInput` for your desired result).

Answer (score 1):

You want [`jQuery.extend`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/), which is explicitly for merging two or more objects (the order of arguments is reversed from your hypothetical `mergeObjects` method):

```
var finalObject = $.extend(defaults, userInput);

finalObject // Object {name: "Pat", color: "green", state: "washington"}
```

Comment: it's worth noting explicitly here that in this example, `defaults` gets modified. This could be a problem if you were doing this a number of times - your defaults wouldn't be the same as they were at the beginning. In that case, http://stackoverflow.com/a/18668971/467386 is probably what you want.